# &#13; not creating a new line in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I am creating a data binding app and for line 3 I want to use `&#13;` to create several lines.

e.g.

```
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "Title", LineTwo = "short desc", LineThree = "Line 1 &#13; Line 2"});
```

However, when I run the application the LineThree is displayed as:

`Line 1 &#13; Line 2`

instead of:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

The text block uses the following xaml:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"  FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is not HTML... `"&#13;"` is an HTML entity code, and won't work in XAML. Use `"\n"` instead.